# XNA 3D Point Clouds

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, kinect

I'm trying to output realtime 3D point clouds (307,200 points) using XNA and Kinect; however, it's been ages since I last used XNA and 4.0 changed several things.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've been modifying the Primitives3D demo but I was kinda hoping that there was a library or something that could help me *NOT* waste too much time on this, as it's just a proof of concept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They've removed the point primitive from XNA 4 due to lack of wide support. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/22/point-sprites-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

To draw a point now you will need to draw a tiny triangle for each point. Primitives3d is a good base for this and makes the buffers very efficiently.

Comment: Would going back to 3.1 save me from going insane? (at least because of this) Would you happen to have some more links on the subject?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to release your application to the Marketplace.

Comment: Not really. As I said, it's just a proof of concept.

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar.  I assume triangles would cause problems since you'd have to make sure they are always facing the camera?

Comment: IF its just a POC and/or only running on windows then the only downsides of sticking with 3.1 is the fact you are stuck in VS2008 and possibly any bugs (there's really not many). Triangles would need to me made front facing - take a look at any of the particle samples out there. To be honest GPUS are probably not well optimised for drawing single points anyway. Its rarely used other than debugs. One other option would be to use line drawing and just make the lines very short!